# Drawing Top Down Multi way Trees using Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am wondering if there exist libraries that could help me draw such figures on  screen quickly using JAVA.

[image: The kind of tree I need to draw]

The dataset and number of nodes etc need to be parametrized.

If no such libraries exist, which tools in Swing would get me started. I want a quick and dirty way to represent this information.

Edit : 
Also it would help if you could tell me what to search on google to get results for such a tailored query.

Comment: Graphviz may be what you're after.  The 3rd graph or so in this page is basically what you draw in your question:  *http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.25/25.01/IntroductiontoGraphviz/index.html*   So a quick'n'dirty way (as you wrote ; ) would be somehow to use/reuse Graphviz from Java ; )

Comment: [`JGraph`](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) might be up to it.

Comment: @Syn Yes  graphviz seems to be an excellent library for me. Thankyou

Comment: @syn if you put this as an answer i will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org) from within Java, converting any Java-based tree structure into the necessary GraphViz formats, and then reading the resulting .png image back into Java. That is probably the easiest approach, in terms of code-to-write (credit goes to SyntaxT3rr0r for proposing it first).

Customizing [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraphdownload.html) would also work, but I doubt that any of the default node-types would cut it. There are examples in the manual covering how to code your own node types and representations. JGraph allows easy graphical editing of node labels and positions, has hierarchical layouts (the type you use for trees); and it supports "ports" of origin (and also destination) for your parent-child edges. You can try their editor demo (included in their default download) if you just want a quick test.